# jQuery: Save a select element option that has been selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Hey guys I am trying to save the option that a user has selected on my form however I am unsure how I can do this.

I will briefly explain my setup...

I have this form on my home page:

```
<form class="form-home form-search">
<select class="form-control select-box">
                 <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                 {
                 echo '
                 <option value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
             </select>
 <button href="used-cars.php">Search</button>
</form>
```

As you can see it is using PHP/MySQL to show the options available.

Okay so I then have this form on another page however the CSS styling is slightly different and it includes a few different select elements.

So when a user has selected an element on the home page all the button does is href to the used-cars.php which lists all of the results.

How can I make it so that jQuery saves the option the user selected on the home page and loads the used-cars.php with those options selected?

Any examples would be great.

EDITED
Example of my second form:

```
<div class="container con-col-listing">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
       <form class="car-finder-container dflt-container">
         <h2 class="h2-finder">Car finder</h2>
         <ul class="toggle-view">
           <li class="li-toggle">
            <h4 class="h4-finder-toggle">Make<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h4>
            <div class="panel">
             <select name="make" class="form-control select-box">
                 <option value="make-any">Make (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 $selected = $make['make'] == $_GET['make']?'selected="selected"':'';
                 echo '
                 <option value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
             </select>
             <select class="form-control last-select select-box">
                 <option value="model-any">Model (Any)</option>
                 <?php while($model = $modelFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                 {
                 echo '
                 <option value="'.$model["Model"].'">'.$model["Model"].'</option>
                 ';
                 } ?>
             </select>
            </div>
           </li>
           <li class="li-toggle">
            <h4 class="h4-finder-toggle">Body type<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h4>
            <div class="panel">
             <input id="four-by-four-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="four-by-four-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">4x4</label>
             <input id="convertible-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="convertible-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Convertible</label>
             <input id="coupe-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="coupe-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Coupe</label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="li-toggle">
            <h4 class="h4-finder-toggle">Transmission<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyph-plus-toggle"></span></h4>
            <div class="panel">
             <input id="automatic-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="automatic-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Automatic</label>
             <input id="manual-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="manual-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Manual</label>
             <input id="semi-auto-checkbox" class="float-checkbox" type="checkbox"/>
             <label for="semi-auto-checkbox" class="label-checkbox">Semi automatic</label>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
         <button href="#" class="btn btn-block car-search-button btn-lg btn-success"><span class="glyphicon car-search-g glyphicon-search"></span> Search cars 
         </button>
         <h4 class="h4-finder"><a href="#">Try our Smart Search </a><span class="glyphicon info-car-search-g glyphicon-info-sign"></span></h4>
       </form>
      </div>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `PHP`, But can't you get the selected options value in server side when the form is submitted? You can create the second page using `PHP` accordingly... Why use jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is with a get request:

```
 <form class="form-home form-search" method="GET" action="used-cars.php">
  <select name="make" class="form-control select-box">
  .....
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
```

and on used-cars.php:

```
 var_dump($_GET['make']);
```

**EDIT**

lets suppose on the form on the first page you have:

```
  <option value="ford">ford</option>
  <option value="pontiac">pontiac</option>
  <option value="fiat">fiat</option>
```

when you hit the submit button `$_GET['make']` on used-cars.php will be whatever was selected lets say `fiat`.

so now on used-cars.php you can do this:

```
 <?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $selected = $make['Make'] == $_GET['make']?'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '
     <option '.$selected.' value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
        ';
  } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, how does it determine what select element options are saved? Is it by the class?

Comment: I have extra select elements on my other form that is all.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at but ill take a guess and edit the answer

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining, I'm still unable to get it to work :/ I've done exactly what you have mentioned in your code example.

Here is the live site: http://www.drivencarsales.co.uk/index.php

When I search it goes to used-cars.php however does not select the option that was selected. 

Any ideas why?

Comment: you have not added `name="make"` to the select on the first page look at the second line from the first snippet above

Comment: Okay I have added that and it's still not functioning, I have just checked and I cant see anything missing.

Comment: I am seeing `?make=FORD` in the browser url on the second page so the first page is correct. I should be seeing `<option selected="selected" value="FORD">FORD</option>` on the second page but i'm not so you got somet5hing wrong on the second page

Comment: Hmm I'm a little confused then to what is causing this, I have edited my post to show my whole form for the second page however I still don't understand why this is occurring, could it be the jQuery I am using to hide the tabbed menu's?

Comment: no, nothing to do with javascript `$selected = $make['make'] == $_GET['make']?'selected="selected"':'';` should cause the the selected option to be chosen. you should have added to the second page

Comment: As you can see by the example in my answer I have added that code though?

Comment: you're not echoing `$selected` when creating the options. see the 4th line in my last snippet above

Comment: I edited the line I'm referring to because i didn't notice you were using single quotes

Comment: Okay so I've added that and uploaded it to the server and still no luck, my option is displaying this code:

<?php while($make = $makeFilter->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $selected = $make['make'] == $_GET['make']?'selected="selected"':'';
    echo '
     <option '.$selected.' value="'.$make["Make"].'">'.$make["Make"].'</option>
        ';
  } ?>

Comment: oh ok your make element has an uppercase 'M' so try this: `$selected = $make['Make'] == $_GET['make']?'selected="selected"':'';`

Comment: Thanks andrew! It's working, the only issue is that when the page loads the results aren't filtered. I guess I'll have to work that one out myself, can't thank you enough!

Comment: prob just do a `$(function(){$('.car-search-button').click()})` to submit on load. Please remember to accept the answer